# How to enable 24-bit color emacs on terminal when opening it from a remote machine?

Tags: colors, ssh

Both of my computers, says A and B, have a terminal that supports 24-bit color. Opening emacs on both terminals also show the 24-bit colors, e.g. executing `M-x list-colors-display` will list 556 different colors instead of the classic 256 colors (8 bit). But if I log in to B through ssh from A, and open the emacs installed on B using the terminal console of A, it shows only 8-bit colors when I execute `M-x list-colors-display`. How do I get all of the colors of B's emacs when opening it from A? Both computers have emacs 28.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked in the [*GNU Emacs FAQ*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Colors-on-a-TTY.html) and found this method, but it seems to only work for GNU/Linux:

> If Terminfo database is not available, but 24-bit direct color mode is supported, it can still be enabled by defining the environment variable `COLORTERM` to ‘`truecolor`’.

And I tried it myself:

```shell
$ export COLORTERM=truecolor
$ emacs -Q
```

then type `M-x list-colors-display`.  It works for me.

Comment: By the way, generally speaking, true color and 24-bit color mean the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me too. I guess the problem is this env variable is not automatically set to `truecolor` when one logs in remotely.